# Strange behaviour of Enum.GetName

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, exception, enums

I have an enum like this:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Character = 'C',
    Number = 'N',
}
```

Then I'm doing something like this:

```
char myChar = 'C';
var value = Enum.GetName(typeof(MyEnum), myChar); //throw exception on .NET 3.5 or less
```

This code is OK in projects with .NET 4 but throws exception on .NET 3.5 or less. This is the exception:

> The value passed in must be an enum base or an underlying type for an
>   enum, such as an Int32.Parameter name: value

So I published my project with .NET 4 and share it with my friends and told them they need .NET4. They run the program successfully **but find out the program throws the same exception on some systems even with .NET 4!** Anyone knows what is the cause of this exception?

I solved the problem this way, but interested to know why it was working on some systems and not working on some others? (all of them has .NET4)

```
var value = Enum.GetName(typeof(MyEnum), (int)myChar);
```

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand? You need to pass a number.

Comment: but it is working in .NET 4 on some systems.

Comment: Can you compare those systems where it works and where it doesn't? It wouldn't surprise me if it's working on those systems (and only those systems) where .NET 4.5 is installed. Even though you're targeting 4.0, 4.5 is an in-place upgrade with a few subtle behavioural changes.

Comment: The subtlety of implicit conversions in C#/VB.NET...

Comment: @hvd Unfortunately I do not have access to those systems right now. and getting information about them requires some steps...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was changed in .NET 4.5.  Beware that it is difficult to see whether you have 4.0 or 4.5 installed on the machine, 4.5 *replaces* 4.0 and uses the same install directory as 4.0.

The method that was changed is the one that @Dirk quoted, the internal IsIntegerType() helper method.  The 4.0 version looks like this:

```
internal static bool IsIntegerType(Type t)
{
    if (((!(t == typeof(int)) && !(t == typeof(short))) && (!(t == typeof(ushort)) && 
          !(t == typeof(byte)))) && ((!(t == typeof(sbyte)) && !(t == typeof(uint))) && 
          !(t == typeof(long))))
    {
        return (t == typeof(ulong));
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note how typeof(char) isn't being tested so it doesn't consider it a valid type for the *value* argument you pass to Enum.GetName().

These kind of changes in a .NET Framework version that is not a side-by-side version are fairly uncool, it does make it awfully hard to diagnose program failure.  Especially since you targeted NET 4.0 in your project but ended up running on a machine that had 4.5 installed so never noticed the problem.  But kaboom on a machine on which only 4.0 is installed.

The best possible spin to put on it that this was a bug in 4.0 that they fixed in 4.5.  And frankly it was, you of course expected a char to be completely valid since that's what you used to initialize the enum members.  It does show how difficult it is for Microsoft to ever fix bugs.

Comment: Do the 4.5 assemblies show up as 4.0.0.0 in the GAC too? I was trying to locate them but couldn't find them with ILSpy.

Comment: Yes, their version numbers are still 4.0.0.0.  Only the ones added in 4.5 have a 4.5.0.0 version number.  I had to copy the 4.0 version of mscorlib.dll off an old machine to write this answer.

Answer (score 3):

The implementation for `Enum.GetName` changed from 2.0 to 4.0.

This is the decompiled version from 2.0 (with ILSpy):

```
public static string GetName(Type enumType, object value)
{
    [...]
    // Enum.intType = typeof(int)
    Type type = value.GetType();
    if (type.IsEnum || type == Enum.intType || type == typeof(short) || type == typeof(ushort) || type == typeof(byte) || type == typeof(sbyte) || type == typeof(uint) || type == typeof(long) || type == typeof(ulong))
    {
        return Enum.InternalGetValueAsString(enumType, value);
    }
    throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_MustBeEnumBaseTypeOrEnum"), "value");
}
```

You can see that for `type = typeof(char)` this exception is throw.

---

And for 4.0 it is:

```
public static string GetName(Type enumType, object value)
{
    [...]
    // this is actually in a method called by GetName, I put it here for clarity
    Type type = value.GetType();
    if (!type.IsEnum && !Type.IsIntegerType(type))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_MustBeEnumBaseTypeOrEnum"), "value");
    }
    [...]
}

// Type.IsIntegerType
internal static bool IsIntegerType(Type t)
{
    return t == typeof(int) || t == typeof(short) || t == typeof(ushort) || t == typeof(byte) || t == typeof(sbyte) || t == typeof(uint) || t == typeof(long) || t == typeof(ulong) || t == typeof(char) || t == typeof(bool);
}
```

But here `type = typeof(char)` doesn't result in the exception.

Comment: This still doesn't answer why it does throw an exception on some systems with .NET 4.

Comment: @hvd The only places where I found this kind of exception all have the same if-check. Are you sure you are executing it with the .NET 4.0 runtime when the exception occurs?

Comment: I'm not the OP, I'm just repeating what the OP already clarified before you posted your answer :)

Comment: @hvd I shouldn't have assumed. Sorry.

Comment: @Dirk helpful answer. How can I guide my friends to find out which CLR is running the program?

Answer (score 1):

The approved types for an enum are `byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong` [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx).

You can't create Enum char value, .NET lets you do this, but compilator converts your char values to its equivalent int representation (ASCII).

Comment: On my systems with .NET 4 I can send character as well (when send 'C' to `GetName` it returns the "Character") and no problem.

Comment: That's correct but he doesn't use chars for the enums underlying values, he only sets the values to the integral value of 'C' and 'N'.

Comment: The main question is why it works on some systems and do not work on some others (all have .NET 4)